# mysqli select function with array parameters

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to create a function where the input are two array's. One for the fields and one for the tables.

```
public function s($fields = array(), $tables = array()) { }
```

but I have no idea how to one from here. I had the idea to loop through the two array's and save each value to a string like this (but this to me like not the best way to do this):

```
$length = count($fields);
$fieldsString = "";

for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $fieldsString += $fields[$i];
}
```

then do the same thing to $tables and output the $fieldsString and $tablesString to a SQL query.

My question: can this be done in a more effective way?

*EDIT*
I know how do to this with for-loop and get the output I want. But I'm looking for a more "professional" way to deal with this problem, to learn from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The OOP Approach:**

First I'll just say that the OOP is much more than just one class in a code. 
It's a concept, that allows us to think in bigger scale, and creates much more functionality in our code.

I created a DBHandler Class which will handle all of my DB Requests what so ever, so it's better to keep that in a separate file, even in a higher hierarchy directory.

This is how the class looks like:

```
<?php
class DBHandler{

    public $dbCon;

    function __construct(mysqli $dbCon){
        $this->dbCon = $dbCon;
    }

    private function createQuery($parameters, $tables){

      $params = implode(',', $parameters);

      $tParam = implode(',',$tables);

    return "SELECT $params FROM $tParam";

    }


    public function query($dbCon, $parameters, $tables){

        $query = createQuery($parameters, $tables);
        $result =$this->dbCon->query($query);
        return $result; 
    }
}
?>
```

And this is how your main should look like:

```
<?php
$myownDB = new DBHandler($dbCon);

$myownDB->query($parameters, $tables);
?>
```

This way is way more maintainable. and I really suggest using it. 
It's easier to separate your database handler from your actual code, so it wont get messy.
Please note, that this call `$myownDB->query($parameters, $tables);` will run the query instantly, and won't `echo` it.

**The Procedural Programming:**

```
<?php
function s($parameters){

    $i = 0;
    $addtoQuery ='';
    for($i =0; $i<count($parameters); $i++){

        $addtoQuery .= $parameters[$i].',';     

    }
    return  substr($addtoQuery, 0, -1);


}
function t($tables){

    $i = 0;
    $addtoQuery ='';
    for($i =0; $i<count($tables); $i++){

        $addtoQuery .= $tables[$i].',';     

    }
    return  substr($addtoQuery, 0, -1);

}

$parameters = array("range", "distance", "which");
$tables = array("north", "south");
$s = s($parameters);
$t = t($tables);
function createQuery($s, $t){

    $query = "SELECT $s FROM $t";
    return $query;
}

echo createQuery($s,$t);
?>
```

**Result of echo => SELECT range,distance,which FROM north,south
Which you can simply add to Mysqli - Query**

If it's not what you were looking for, I'm sorry.

Good luck!

Comment: the output of your code is what I'm looking for. I would've done it the same way with my knowledge (for-loop stuff). I just wanted to see if there's a more simple way of doing this.

Comment: You mean a simple way to create the query?

Comment: more like a pro way to do this, I'll edit my question

Comment: Oh Professional way.. that is just the quick and simple Procedural programming. The professional way is in the OOP of PHP. I'll write a class to show you the advantage

Comment: And yeah use Implode is much more faster

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looping through the whole Array, you could also use `implode()` to create a string containing all the elements of the array:

```
$ieldsString = implode(',' , $fields);
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.implode.php